# Rust Book Guessing Game Custom Type Validation

Tags: rust

In the Rust book, [Chapter 9.3 To panic! or Not to panic!, section Creating Custom Types for Validation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-03-to-panic-or-not-to-panic.html#creating-custom-types-for-validation), they have the snippet

```rust
    loop {
        // --snip--

        let guess: i32 = match guess.trim().parse() {
            Ok(num) => num,
            Err(_) => continue,
        };

        if guess < 1 || guess > 100 {
            println!("The secret number will be between 1 and 100.");
            continue;
        }

        match guess.cmp(&secret_number) {
            // --snip--
    }
```

and suggest that it's better to create a custom type that checks the variants where the value should be between 1 and 100 via

```rust
pub struct Guess {
    value: i32,
}

impl Guess {
    pub fn new(value: i32) -> Guess {
        if value < 1 || value > 100 {
            panic!("Guess value must be between 1 and 100, got {}.", value);
        }

        Guess { value }
    }

    pub fn value(&self) -> i32 {
        self.value
    }
}
```

So this means that the new code using the Guess struct should be

```rust
    loop {
        // --snip--

        let guess: Guess = match guess.trim().parse() {
            Ok(num) => Guess::new(num),
            Err(_) => continue,
        };

        match guess.cmp(&secret_number) {
            // --snip--
    }
```

However, I'm confused with where the input validation logic goes now

```rust
        if guess < 1 || guess > 100 {
            println!("The secret number will be between 1 and 100.");
            continue;
        }
```

The constructor

```rust
Guess::new(num)
```

panics if an invalid number is given. So shouldn't `Guess::new` return a `Result` so that we can handle this and let the user know that the secret number is between 1 and 100?

In the book it also says

> A function that has a parameter or returns only numbers between 1 and 100 could then declare in its signature that it takes or returns a Guess rather than an i32 and wouldn’t need to do any additional checks in its body.

So is this implying that we should have another function that does the actual input validation, and then it returns the `Guess` object? Something like

```rust
fn check_input(value: i32) -> Result<Guess, String> {
    if value < 1 || value > 100 {
        return Err(String::from("The secret number will be between 1 and 100."));
    }

    Ok(Guess::new(value))
}

// ...
    loop {
        // --snip--

        let guess: i32 = match guess.trim().parse() {
            Ok(num) => num,
            Err(_) => continue,
        };

        let guess: Guess = match check_input(guess) {
            Ok(result) => result,
            Err(msg) => {
                println!("{}", msg);
                continue;
            },
        };
    }
// ...
```

If `Guess::new` returns a `Result` instead, then we wouldn't need to create the `check_input` function. And we wouldn't be duplicating the validation logic (we now have the input validation in both the Guess constructor and also the check_input function). What are the advantages of the latter approach? Or am I misunderstanding what the book is suggesting?

Comment: If you `panic!` doesn't really matter if you return `Result`. What you should do is define an `Error` implementation you can return instead, or even just use `&'static str`.

Comment: As you learn more Rust you might come to realize this `new()` should actually be `impl TryFrom<i32> for Guess` as [`TryFrom`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/trait.TryFrom.html) already has the skeleton you need. Other languages steer towards `new()` with exceptions, but Rust takes a different approach, at least for trivial constructors that have validation rules.

Comment: Right, so that makes sense. If I didn't know that `TryFrom` exists, then `new()` returning a `Result<Guess, &'static str>` instead of panicking would be sensible, right? That way we can return the message `The secret number will be between 1 and 100.` back to the user and let them try again without having to duplicate and create another function like `check_input` (seen in my example)

Comment: Yeah, that's certainly a good first step. The nice thing about Rust is you can evolve from that simple design to something much better over time almost seamlessly, for example, `eprintln!("Error: {}", err)` will work with `&str` and later on if you implement your own `Error` (which requires `Display`). Gives you a chance to evolve your errors into more formalized forms without breaking a lot of dependencies.

Comment: In your case I'd see this as a validation + creation attempt rolled into one structured around `match Guess::try_from(guess)`. As you get more into Rust you'll see that sort of pattern used all over, or even later on, `let guess = Guess::try_from(n)?`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you panic on invalid values in the constructor, you should validate the input before calling it:

```rust
    loop {
        // --snip--

        let guess: i32 = match guess.trim().parse() {
            Ok(num) => num,
            Err(_) => continue,
        };

        if guess < 1 || guess > 100 {
            println!("The secret number will be between 1 and 100.");
            continue;
        }

        let guess = Guess::new(guess);

        match guess.cmp(&secret_number) {
            // --snip--
    }
```

At this point, since you don't do much with the `Guess` object, I don't think there is value in it.

You can also choose to return `Result` (or `Option`) in the constructor. This will be my preferred option in this situation, as this avoids the double validation. Another common practice is to have a panicking `new()` constructor and a non-panicking `try_new()`, in case both are needed.

> So is this implying that we should have another function that does the actual input validation, and then it returns the `Guess` object?

I don't think; you can certainly do this, but I think what the book is saying is that if you have a function that is *known* to only return numbers between 1 and 100 (and it should also be returning some guess, otherwise using `Guess` doesn't make sense) it can return a `Guess`.